# What Apache/PHP/Server settings might affect the speed of a CodeIgniter model instantiation from one server to another?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, apache2

One of the pages in one of my apps runs very slowly on the web server compared to my local test server.  There are some radical differences in the environments that might explain it, but I'm hoping for a more solvable solution than that.

Server:
Solaris 10
Apache 2.2.9 Prefork
PHP 5.2.6
The server is run on a cluster of 4 not-even-a-year-old Sun boxes, and shouldn't be having any issues performance-wise.

Local Test Server:
Windows XP
Apache 2.2.14 WinNT
PHP 5.3.1
This is actually my own desktop - a decent machine, but should pale in comparison to the Sun boxes.

The application is written with CodeIgniter, and I've used the profiling features within to trace the slowdown to Model::Model().  For example, Model::Model() runs in 0.0006s locally and 0.0045s on the server. When you're loading hundreds of models on a page, this is obviously an issue.

I've cross-posted this here from ServerFault, as it could, potentially, be more closely related to CodeIgniter.

From local, the page takes 2-3 seconds to load. From the server, it's 11-15.

Modules on Local, but not remote:

- mod_actions
- mod_asis
- mod_dav
  mod_dav_fs
- mod_dav_lock
- mod_isapi
  mod_autoindex_color

Modules on remote, not Local:

- mod_authn_dbm
- mod_authn_anon
- mod_authz_dbm
- mod_authz_owner
- mod_cache
- mod_mem_cache
- mod_deflate
- mod_authnz_ldap
- mod_ldap
- mod_mime_magic
- mod_expires
- mod_unique_id
- mod_autoindex
- mod_suexec
- mod_userdir
- libphp5
- mod_dtrace
- mod_security2

---

**Edit:**

I've been moving my benchmarking progressively down, level by level, and have found the largest discrepancy lies within this chunk of code (which is in the CodeIgniter function Model::_assign_libraries, and is called during a model's constructor):

```
    $time = microtime()*1000;
    foreach (array_keys(get_object_vars($CI)) as $key)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->$key) AND $key != $this->_parent_name)
        {
            // In some cases using references can cause
            // problems so we'll conditionally use them
            if ($use_reference == TRUE)
            {
                $this->$key = NULL; // Needed to prevent reference errors with some configurations
                $this->$key =& $CI->$key;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->$key = $CI->$key;
            }
        }
    }
    if (get_class($this) == 'SeatType')
        echo sprintf('%.5f ms|', (microtime()*1000 - $time));
```

Locally, this prints around 0.48ms every iteration. On the cluster, it prints around 3.9ms every iteration.

I'm beginning to wonder if this problem is outside of Apache/PHP - I copied both the php.ini and htconf files to my local server, and (after removing mod_dtrace, and pretty much nothing else), I actually saw increased performance. (The above check now prints .2ms locally.)

Comment: Are you sure it's not database related? Slow queries perhaps?

Comment: It is doing a ton of queries, however the largest runs in 0.0391 locally, and 0.0078 on the cluster.

Comment: try playing with the persistent connection setting (`$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; // or FALSE`) in database configuration file. See if it helps.

Comment: I would have expected turning it off to have drastically decreased performance, but it in fact had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Is the cluster site live? The server load/traffic can affect processing time. Also, consider using the worker MPM(and/or adjusting the MPM settings) instead of prefork as it can improve overall performance(not necessarily CI). And make sure your database is properly indexed.

Comment: No, it is not live.  This server is for internal development only.  Trust me, I would give anything to be able to use Worker MPM here.  Unfortunately, we run Coolstack which doesn't support it.

Comment: Also, you probably don't have any latency developing on your local computer, not to mention you'd probably need to know the specs on the other computer rather than that it's just a "cluster".

Comment: I don't have the specs for the cluster, I can't find that document.

I know it's not a latency issue due to my benchmarking showing a large discrepancy in a specific place of my code.

Comment: half a second to initialise some modules is definitely issue with application logic, just wondering how many database queries being called during this process?

Also incorrect usage of MOD_REWRITE can also dramatically decrease server performance.

Comment: Mod_rewrite? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have discovered is that though the SPARC servers look as though they should perform better than the core2 quad in my PC, they do this completely by threading.  Any single thread will actually perform worse.  The decrease in performance is likely due to this.